# Prevent bitmap beign sent to next activity (Intent)

Tags: java, android, http, android-intent, bitmap

I'm developing an Android app (Java) for storeroom control and I need to send the employee signature (image) through HTTP request (Volley) to the database server. The data and the image are correctly stored in server, but then an error makes the app stop:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not copy bitmap to parcel blob`, altought I'm not trying to send the image in the Intent to any Activity. I've tried without passing the idUsuario/nombreUsuario params to next activity, delete the generated image after sending it through the HTTP request, but error keeps showing up.

The code:

````
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.ctc.controlgarita.data.Empleado;
import com.github.gcacace.signaturepad.views.SignaturePad;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class FirmaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String firmaEncoded;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_firma);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Button buttonBorrarFirma = findViewById(R.id.buttonBorrarFirma);
        Button buttonEnviarRegistro = findViewById(R.id.buttonEnviarRegistro);

        SignaturePad signaturePad = findViewById(R.id.signature_pad);
        signaturePad.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

        signaturePad.setOnSignedListener(new SignaturePad.OnSignedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStartSigning() {
                // No se necesita
            }

            @Override
            public void onSigned() {
                buttonBorrarFirma.setEnabled(true);
                buttonEnviarRegistro.setEnabled(true);
            }

            @Override
            public void onClear() {
                buttonBorrarFirma.setEnabled(false);
                buttonEnviarRegistro.setEnabled(false);
            }
        });

        buttonBorrarFirma.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                signaturePad.clear();
            }
        });

        String nombreUsuario = intent.getStringExtra("nombreUsuario");
        String idUsuario = intent.getStringExtra("idUsuario");

        String tipoRegistro = intent.getStringExtra("tipoRegistro");
        String llave = intent.getStringExtra("llave");
        String corpo = intent.getStringExtra("corpo");
        String numeroMovil = intent.getStringExtra("numeroMovil");
        String numeroCorpo = intent.getStringExtra("numeroCorpo");
        String idEmpleado = intent.getStringExtra("idEmpleado");

        buttonEnviarRegistro.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            final Bitmap[] signatureBitmap = {signaturePad.getSignatureBitmap()};

            signatureBitmap[0].compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
            byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
            firmaEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);

            String url = "http://SOME_IP_ADDRESS/wsGarita/ingresarRegistro.php";
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                    response -> {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            boolean success = jsonObject.getBoolean("success");

                            if (success) {
                                Intent nextIntent = new Intent(FirmaActivity.this, FinRegistroActivity.class);

                                nextIntent.putExtra("nombreUsuario", nombreUsuario);
                                nextIntent.putExtra("idUsuario", idUsuario);

                                startActivity(nextIntent);

                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(FirmaActivity.this, "ERROR al ingresar registro", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(FirmaActivity.this, "ERROR al procesar JSON", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    },
                    error -> {
                        Log.e("ErrorVolley", error.toString());
                    }) {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                    // Parámetros para la solicitud POST
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                    params.put("tipo_registro", tipoRegistro);
                    params.put("empleado_id", idEmpleado);
                    params.put("registro_llave", llave);
                    params.put("registro_corpo", corpo);
                    params.put("numero_movil", numeroMovil);
                    params.put("numero_corpo", numeroCorpo);
                    params.put("usuario_id", idUsuario);
                    params.put("firma", firmaEncoded);
                    return params;
                }
            };

            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        });
    }
} ```

``` FinRegistroAtivity:
public class FinRegistroActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fin_registro);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        TextView toolbarTitle = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
        Intent intent = getIntent();

        String nombreUsuario = intent.getStringExtra("nombreUsuario");
        String idUsuario = intent.getStringExtra("idUsuario");

        if (toolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false); // Deshabilitar el título predeterminado

                if (nombreUsuario != null) {
                    toolbarTitle.setText(getString(R.string.toolbar_title, nombreUsuario));
                }
            }
        } // end if toolbar

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent nextIntent = new Intent(FinRegistroActivity.this, RegistroActivity.class);

                nextIntent.putExtra("idUsuario", idUsuario);
                nextIntent.putExtra("nombreUsuario", nombreUsuario);

                startActivity(nextIntent);
            }
        }, 2500);
    }
} ```

Stack trace:

```Reducing the number of considered missed Gc histogram windows from 407 to 100
2023-12-18 09:39:30.177  5179-5207  Parcel                  com.ctc.controlgarita                W  Expecting binder but got null!
2023-12-18 09:39:30.716  5179-5179  ActivityStopInfo        com.ctc.controlgarita                W  Bundle stats:
2023-12-18 09:39:30.719  5179-5179  ActivityStopInfo        com.ctc.controlgarita                W    android:viewHierarchyState [size=1428]
2023-12-18 09:39:30.722  5179-5179  ActivityStopInfo        com.ctc.controlgarita                W      android:views [size=1380]
2023-12-18 09:39:30.726  5179-5179  ActivityStopInfo        com.ctc.controlgarita                W    androidx.lifecycle.BundlableSavedStateRegistry.key [size=1228]
2023-12-18 09:39:30.726  5179-5179  ActivityStopInfo        com.ctc.controlgarita                W  PersistableBundle stats:
2023-12-18 09:39:30.726  5179-5179  ActivityStopInfo        com.ctc.controlgarita                W    [null]
2023-12-18 09:39:30.727  5179-5179  AndroidRuntime          com.ctc.controlgarita                D  Shutting down VM
2023-12-18 09:39:30.732  5179-5179  AndroidRuntime          com.ctc.controlgarita                E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.ctc.controlgarita, PID: 5179
                                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not copy bitmap to parcel blob.
                                                                                                        at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeWriteToParcel(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at android.graphics.Bitmap.writeToParcel(Bitmap.java:2140)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:2538)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2439)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2316)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:1265)
                                                                                                        at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1802)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1389)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:1334)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2433)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2323)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.writeSparseArray(Parcel.java:1422)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2463)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2316)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:1265)
                                                                                                        at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1802)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1389)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:1334)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2433)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:2323)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:1265)
                                                                                                        at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1802)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1389)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedObject(Parcel.java:2157)
                                                                                                        at android.app.IActivityClientController$Stub$Proxy.activityStopped(IActivityClientController.java:1277)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityClient.activityStopped(ActivityClient.java:86)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions$StopInfo.run(PendingTransactionActions.java:143)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
2023-12-18 09:39:30.750  5179-5179  Process                 com.ctc.controlgarita                I  Sending signal. PID: 5179 SIG: 9
---------------------------- PROCESS ENDED (5179) for package com.ctc.controlgarita ----------------------------
---------------------------- PROCESS STARTED (9849) for package com.ctc.controlgarita ----------------------------```
````

Comment: Pretty unclear where this is about. Or you send an image to a server on internet or try to send it to another activity. Or both. But what are you doing?

Comment: @blackapps I only need to send the image to my server, nothing else, I don't need to send it to another activity. The next activity only shows a success message.

Comment: An error message i think. About copying a bitmap to a blob? How is that possible if you are not messing around with an image to send it to an activity too?

Comment: if it's too big to send to another activity, then consider not sending it to an activity. perhaps, use fragments instead

Comment: that's what i don't understand, it looks like a bug or something, as you can see in the code im not passing the image to other activity at all.

@a_local_nobody as I stated before to blackapps, I'm not sending the image to other activity, I only send it in a HTTP request, nothing else.

Comment: Then where and when do you get that error message ,(which you call a success message?)

Comment: What happens if you do NOT start another activity?

Comment: @blackapps When the HTTP request is successful, I jump to the next activity ```if (success) {
                                Intent nextIntent = new Intent(FirmaActivity.this, FinRegistroActivity.class);```, here is where the app crashes. In logcat says ```java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not copy bitmap to parcel blob```

Comment: @blackapps if i dont start the next activity the app keeps running without that error, but its something i need to show to the user so he/she will know the task was performed correctly, then returns to the start automatically after 3 seconds. Also prevents from going back through the form that was already sent.

Comment: I recommend that you edit your question and post the entire stack trace, not just the error message.

Comment: We dont know what the next activity is doing. But when it comes with that bitmap/blob message ist is doing something with a bitmap and a blob we assume.

Comment: I've added the next activity code. @CommonsWare edited to share the stack trace.

Comment: Your next activity also immediately launched a following activity using a handler. Pretty unclear where that bitmap/blog would come up. Do not launch that activity for a test.

Comment: `activityStopped` suggests that your crash is coming from the saved instance state `Bundle`, not an `Intent` extra.

Comment: I've deleted almost everything in the last activity (FinRegistroActivity) and the intent to RegistroActivity (the first of all) and keeps crashing. IMO the problem is in FirmaActivity, where the .png of the signature is created (bitmap), right when starts FinRegistroActivity, i think Intent is grabbing the image as an Extra altought is not intented to do that in the code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76969254/how-to-resolve-could-not-copy-bitmap-to-parcel-blob-in-android-12 this is the same problem, with the difference im not storing the image.

Comment: Are you messing around with your bitmap in onSaveInstanceState() ?

Comment: `final Bitmap[] signatureBitmap` Dont make it final.

Comment: I tried without making ```signatureBitmap``` final but it didn't work. I ended giving up and added the method ```finish()``` after start the next activity:
```Intent nextIntent = new Intent(FirmaActivity.this, FinRegistroActivity.class);

                                nextIntent.putExtra("nombreUsuario", nombreUsuario);
                                nextIntent.putExtra("idUsuario", idUsuario);

                                startActivity(nextIntent);
                                finish();```